# Seleccionar el Ultimo valor

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas **entrada** y **compra** cada una relacionada con su detalle: **detalle_entrada** y **compra_detalle**, de las cuales quiero sacar el último costo de un **producto** que será delimitado por la fecha más reciente, ya sea de la entrada o de la compra.

Lo tengo solucionado parcialmente usando **UNION** pero me arroja dos resultados. Quisiera saber como puedo seleccionar uno nadamas.

Esta es la consulta:

```
            SELECT IFNULL(
                (SELECT  detalle_entrada.costo   FROM producto 

                INNER JOIN detalle_entrada ON detalle_entrada.idproducto = producto.idproducto
                INNER JOIN entrada ON entrada.identrada = detalle_entrada.identrada

                WHERE producto.idproducto = 153

                ORDER BY entrada.fecha_entrada DESC

                LIMIT 1),            
            0.0) as ultimo_costo

            UNION

            SELECT IFNULL(
                (SELECT compra_detalle.precio_unitario FROM producto 

                INNER JOIN compra_detalle ON compra_detalle.idproducto = producto.idproducto
                INNER JOIN compra ON compra.idcompra = compra.idcompra

                WHERE producto.idproducto = 153

                ORDER BY compra.fecha_compra DESC

                LIMIT 1),            
            0.0) as ultimo_costo
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: vos queres que todo salga en una sola fila? y si en lugar de union pones una consulta al lado de la otra?

Comment: @gbianchi no, lo que pasa que en la tabla **entrada** y **compra** registro movimientos en el inventario de productos y como tal en ambos ingreso el costo del producto, entonces se me ocurrió hacer una **UNION** para poder buscar el producto y filtrarlo por la última entrada o compra según la fecha y así obtener el costo.

Comment: Si pero igual, haces un select igual q ahora, y reemplazas el union por una coma... no te lo devuelve en una fila?

Comment: Intenté sustituir UNION por la coma y me marcaba un error de sintaxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir un 'limit' al final de la sentencia

Ejemplo: Te da el **primer resultado**

```
select 'a' 
union 
select 'b' limit 1
```

Si, quieres solo el **segundo resultado** usa:

```
limit 1,1
```

Comment: me parece que quiere que todo salga en una fila.

Comment: Si me resolvió parcialmente el problema, en cuanto termine la solución la comparto.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno estuve haciendo varias pruebas y gracias a la sugerencia de @Yasti resolví parte de la problemática y al final así me quedó la consulta:

```
SELECT detalle_costo.costo FROM (

(SELECT compra_detalle.precio_unitario as costo, compra.fecha_compra as fecha FROM producto 

                        INNER JOIN compra_detalle ON compra_detalle.idproducto = producto.idproducto
                        INNER JOIN compra ON compra.idcompra = compra.idcompra

                        WHERE producto.idproducto = 153

                        ORDER BY compra.fecha_compra DESC

                        limit 1)

    UNION

(SELECT detalle_entrada.costo as costo, entrada.fecha_entrada as fecha FROM producto 

                        INNER JOIN detalle_entrada ON detalle_entrada.idproducto = producto.idproducto
                        INNER JOIN entrada ON entrada.identrada = detalle_entrada.identrada

                        WHERE producto.idproducto = 153

                        ORDER BY entrada.fecha_entrada DESC

                        limit 1)

    ) AS detalle_costo 

    ORDER BY detalle_costo.fecha DESC

    LIMIT 1
```

El resultado con LIMIT 1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sin el LIMIT 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo esta solucion. El limit 1, es lo mismo que ejecutaras solo la primera parte, o necesitabas obtener el menos de los dos? me parece que planteaste mal el problema.